# conversion of numpy.str_ to byte or string datatype error

Tags: python, string, numpy, type-conversion, byte

I have multiple hex values in a function with data type **numpy.str_**. I want to return these values with string or byte data type. I am getting error while converting **numpy.str_** to **str** or **bytes**. I have used **numpy.fromstring(A, dtype=bytes)** where A is in numpy.str_. The values of "A" be like:
4eb96fd03740f34b054136b367996ce8adf76acec0fc98ef2506bf533474eae1

The Attached [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwW9f.png) shows the part of code from a function in right-hand side. The output is shown from within the function and from outside the function. I want to convert the datatype of values in each index. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `np.str_` is a subclass of Python `str`.  `A.tolist()` should return a `str` (or list of strings if `A` is an array).

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Yes, 'A.tolist()' returned the 'str' values. Thanks.
Later after a few steps, while decrypting these values with AES_CBC using Pycryptodome, I am facing a padding issue (while everything seems good with coding, there might be a 'type' issue). I am still figuring out the problem.

Comment: @hpaulj that is strange I have a numpy string array and all of the elements inside are of ```numpy.str_``` class, I had to do ```arr = [str(item) for item in arr]``` to convert np.str_ to string

Comment: @SeanWilliam, What was the `arr.dtype`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `repr()` cast instead of `str()`. I had the same issue when tried to create request for *Redis* to load a list

```
sentinel = Sentinel([(h, port) for h in hosts], socket_timeout=0.5, password=password)
service_name = service_name
master = sentinel.master_for(service_name, password=self.password)
master.rpush(repr(key), 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

*key* was an *numpy.str_* and simple casting by `str(key)` don't give bytes, what is necessary for Redis requests.

Wish you luck!